# Initialise output location outside of rmarkdown::render

Tags: r-markdown

[Mikko Marttila](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173343/dynamically-naming-the-output-file-in-a-custom-r-markdown-function) helped me to find a way to dynamically timestamp files, using the **working** code below:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Jane Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: word_document
knit: >
(function(input_file, encoding) {
# Render, keeping intermediate files for extracting front matter
md_dir <- tempdir()
output_file_temp <- rmarkdown::render(
  input = input_file,
  output_file = tempfile(),
  intermediates_dir = md_dir,
  clean = FALSE
)

# Get the rendered front matter from the intermediate Markdown file
md_file <- fs::path_ext_set(fs::path_file(input_file), ".knit.md")
metadata <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(fs::path(md_dir, md_file))

# Build the output file name based on rendered metadata
output_name <- with(metadata, paste(title, "by", author, "on", date))

# Add the file extension and move to the working directory
output_ext <- fs::path_ext(output_file_temp)
output_file <- fs::path_ext_set(output_name, output_ext)
fs::file_move(output_file_temp, output_file)

message("Output moved to: ", output_file)
})
---
```

I would however additionally like to specify the output location from within the `knitr` code, based on the `projectmanager` and `project`. The folder should be created if it does not yet exist.

This could be done as follows: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733147/creating-a-new-folder-from-within-r-markdown). I have tried to combine these solutions.

I have tried to do this as in a couple of different ways, but somehow I can't get it to work.

**Desired output location:**

```
.../projectname/project")
```

I tried using `setwd` as well as using  `file.path` :

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Jane Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: word_document
projectmanager: "Earth Worm Jim"
project: "getstuffdone"
knit: >
  (function(input_file, encoding) {
    # Render, keeping intermediate files for extracting front matter
    md_dir <- tempdir()
    output_file_temp <- rmarkdown::render(
      input = input_file,
      output_file = tempfile(),
      intermediates_dir = md_dir,
      clean = FALSE
    )
    
    # Get the rendered front matter from the intermediate Markdown file
    md_file <- fs::path_ext_set(fs::path_file(input_file), ".knit.md")
    metadata <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(fs::path(md_dir, md_file))
    # Tom: Specify the main directory in which to store all folders
    main_directory <- "Z:/Coding/R_scripts/Markdown/RMarkdown_out/"
    # Check current working directory
    print(getwd())
    # print(metadata)

    # Dynamically create a full path for the new file based on projectmanager and project
    out_dir <- with(metadata, paste0(main_directory, projectmanager, "/", project, "/"))
    print(out_dir)

    # Here I tried to set the working directory to the dynamically created wd
    setwd(out_dir)
    print(getwd())

    # Build output file name based on rendered metadata
    output_name <- with(metadata, paste(title, date, initials))
    print(output_name)
    output_dir = file.path(dirname(output_name), out_dir)
    print(output_dir)

    # path_ext() returns the last extension (if any) for a path
    output_ext <- fs::path_ext(output_file_temp) 
    print(output_ext)
    
    # replaces the extension with a new extension path_ext_set(path, ext)
    output_file <- fs::path_ext_set(output_name, output_ext) 
    print(output_file)

    fs::file_move(output_file_temp, output_file)
    message("Output file: ", output_file)
  })
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to also add a step to create the output directory if needed, and remember to use the created directory when moving the rendered file.

I would steer clear from changing the working directory in a script. Working with the full paths directly tends to lead to easier to understand code.

Here's a modified version with the missing steps added:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Jane Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: word_document
projectmanager: "Earth Worm Jim"
project: "getstuffdone"
knit: >
  (function(input_file, encoding) {
    # Render, keeping intermediate files for extracting front matter
    md_dir <- tempdir()
    rendered_file <- rmarkdown::render(
      input = input_file,
      output_file = tempfile(),
      intermediates_dir = md_dir,
      clean = FALSE
    )
    
    # Get the rendered front matter from the intermediate Markdown file
    md_file <- fs::path_ext_set(fs::path_file(input_file), ".knit.md")
    metadata <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(fs::path(md_dir, md_file))
    
    # Directory that the output is relative to. Can be an absolute path.
    OUTPUT_ROOT <- "."
    
    # Build the output file name and directory based on rendered metadata
    output_dir <- with(metadata, fs::path(projectmanager, project))
    output_name <- with(metadata, paste(title, "by", author, "on", date))
    
    # Add the file extension
    output_ext <- fs::path_ext(rendered_file)
    output_file <- fs::path_ext_set(output_name, output_ext)
    
    # Combine parts to final path
    output_path <- fs::path(OUTPUT_ROOT, output_dir, output_file)
    
    # Create output directory if it doesn't exist
    output_path_dir <- fs::path_dir(output_path)
    if (!fs::dir_exists(output_path_dir)) {
      fs::dir_create(output_path_dir)
    }
    
    # Move render result to output location
    fs::file_move(rendered_file, output_path)
    message("Output moved to: ", output_path)
  })
---
```

Comment: If you wanted to standardize the output root directory across different R Markdown files, you could do that with an environment variable, and use `OUTPUT_ROOT <- Sys.getenv("RMARKDOWN_OUTPUT_ROOT", ".")` instead of a path hard-coded into each script.

Comment: This is great Mikko! Thank you so much! I apparently have to wait 21 hrs with giving you the bounty, so I will do that tomorrow!

Comment: Hi Mikka, I found out that your solution (the part that dynamically names files using `rmarkdown::render` (I think), has some unexpected (for me at least) effects on the application of `list2env`, because it probably creates these list in the environment rendered in the `yaml` code instead of the "actual` `knitr` code further down: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097272/listing-to-knitr-environment-r-markdown-error-when-using-list2env-in-r-chunks. Do you have any idea how to prevent this from happening?